# Why is Ubuntu showing a permission error on ec2 while using apache2?

Tags: permissions, apache2, amazon-ec2

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 instance of AWS. I am trying to execute my file using PHP and apache2. But I am getting the following permission error:

```
Sorry, user www-data is not allowed to execute '/usr/local/bin/questansgen sample.txt' 
as www-data on ip-172-31-11-122.ec2.internal. 
drwxrwsrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 20 08:22 . 
-rwxrw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 301 Apr 20 11:15 /usr/local/bin/questansgen
```

How can I remove this error and grant executable permission to the `www-data` user of apache2?

Comment: That is a normal message when you issue "sudo" and are not allowed to use that command with it. So check `/etc/sudoers` and make sure www-data is allowed to do this. But be careful: this smells like a security hole to me.

Comment: I tried this but I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: Why not? I believe your system is trying to use sudo with www-data user and that user is not a sudo user. It is a pretty common message when using "sudo" with a normal user(?) One method is to remove "sudo"
 from the command that is used? Or make an exception for www-data so it can use sudo for this command. What is the software you installed that does this? Does it not have a note on this? Cuz this seems rather crucial to me.

Comment: I am just running a php script that using the `shell_exec` command and running the python command. And nothing else. simple python executable